# ifconfig error showing invalid errors for ifconfig en0 | grep ether

Tags: macos, command-line

Whenever I run `ifconfig en0 | grep ether` it gives me *"ifconfig: invalid arguments"*.

Later I found out that there is something wrong with my ifconfig command and it's not the original one. The man page of ifconfig says *GNU inetutils 1.9.3-dirty* at the end.

How do I get back the original one?

Comment: Are you using a Mac?  The `ifconfig` command is based on BSD, not GNU.

Comment: @Allan It's a brew installled formula probably (inetutils?)...

Comment: Simply use `/sbin/ifconfig en0 | grep ether` temporarily until the problem is fixed...

Comment: actually i can't use the ARP() function of scapy for sending ARP request because by default this uses the /usr/local/bin ifconfig as a result the function fails so can u please tell how can i change my default ifconfig?

Comment: @AMISHASHREYA Your PATH component *".../opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:..."* indicates that [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org/) is installed. I set it up in a Catalina VM temporarily and after installing a newer version of inetutils with `ports` I get all its tools prefixed with a *g*  by default. Can you verify that MacPorts is installed in your environment? Additionally check whether *inetutils* was installed by MacPorts.

Comment: @klanomath - retracted my close vote.

Comment: If you don't need the GNU version of ifconfig (from inettools), do `brew uninstall inetutils`.   This usually does not happen by accident - you have to do steps to put Brew's commands ahead of your system ones. It's normally OK to have brew commands shadow (first in path) the macOS commands, but because of what's happened here you might want to only do that on a per-command basis, using 'GNUBINS', or even traditional aliases. With something as essential as ifconfig, it's not obvious to check if it got shadowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The which command will show what path a command is running:

```
me@dev ~ % which ifconfig
/sbin/ifconfig
```

So, you see on my dev machine, the standard path to the program. You could run fully qualified paths to get the default macos versions of these tools and be “most canonical” no matter which other versions are installed:

```
/sbin/ifconfig en0 | /usr/bin/grep ether
```

Comment: Hello thanks a lot for this but could you please tell me how can i change my ifconfig to use this default path?

Comment: Klanomath has that extra detail correct @AMISHASHREYA - why not archive or delete your dot files and set the, up now that you know $PATH is what let’s other programs hop in front of the system ones.

Answer (score 2):

You probably installed *inetutils 1.9.3* with a package manager like brew or MacPorts.

Besides GNU versions of various tools (telnet, rsh etc.) it also installs a GNU version of ifconfig.

To distinguish the GNU tools from macOS tools with the same names they are usually linked from the install dir (installed with brew this is: /usr/local/opt/inetutils/gnubin) to a directory in the standard PATH prefixed with a *g* (e.g. ifconfig > gifconfig or ftp > gftp).

If you add this install dir to your PATH variable in a way that gives preference over the standard paths, the GNU tools will be executed instead of the original ones.

---

Check your PATH variable: `echo $PATH`. You will likely see something like:

```
/usr/local/opt/inetutils/gnubin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:...
```

Now edit the file which determines your PATH variable (probably either ~/.bashrc or ~/.bash_profile) and remove the gnubin path.

Example: `nano ./bash_profile`

```
...
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/inetutils/gnubin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH"
...
```

Change this to:

```
...
export PATH="/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH"
...
```

Then close the Terminal window or relaunch Terminal.app. This will "reenable" the standard versions of the commands. The GNU tools are still available by entering a command prefixed with a *g* (e.g. `gifconfig` or `gftp`).

Comment: hey my echo $PATH is /usr/local/opt/libxml2/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/TeX/texbin:/Applications/Wireshark.app/Contents/MacOS

Comment: @AMISHASHREYA Please add the result of `echo $PATH` in your question by [editing](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/388732/edit) it